# A problem regarding Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: number-theory

A Linear Diophantine Equation is of the following form: 
Ax+By+C=0, where,gcd(A,B)=d and A=da,B=db.If (x1,y1) is a solution of the diophantine equation, every solution is of the form:
x=x1+bt,y=y1−at
∀t∈Z.

Why is negative t(-t) considered for y? Can anyone explain me it with better clarification?.

Comment: If x2 is larger than x1, y2 should intuitively be smaller than y1.

Comment: Just insert the terms for $x$ and $y$ in the equation $Ax+By+C=0$ to see that only with $-at$, the solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you add $bt$ to $x$, then you must remove something from $y$, in order to the sum $Ax+By$ remains constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
Ax + By + C &=0\\\\
dax + dby + C &=0\\\\
da(x_1+bt)+db(y_1-at)+C&=0\\\\
dax_1+dabt+dby_1-dbat+C&=0
\end{align*}$$
Because $(x_1,y_1)$ is a solution, we know that these terms cancel,
$$dax_1+dby_1+C=0$$
and because we used the negative $-t$ in the expression $y=y_1-at$, the terms
$$dabt-dbat=0$$
cancel too.